# Postgresql - Is there a way to include two tables in "setof" so that two tables are returned instead of one?

Tags: postgresql

The title pretty much says it all. Im trying to return two tables by including the two table names in the setof. This didnt seem to work out. Is there another way I could include both tables in the return?

Comment: You can return multiple ref-cursors. But apart from that it's not possible.

Comment: Why do you need it? What are your tables and what do you want to achieve?